# "Safely remove drive" option missing from Nautilus in 12.10

Tags: nautilus, 12.10, usb-drive, unmount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to safely remove a USB external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203934/how-to-safely-remove-a-usb-external-drive)

`Safely remove drive` option is missing from Nautilus in 12.10 or am I missing something?

In 12.04 I could right click on the USB drive under `Devices` in Nautilus and select `Safely remove drive`. How do I make that option available in 12.10?

Edit: When I say USB drive I mean a USB HDD, not a USB stick or SSD.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of bug reports and some reasons as to why Eject has substituted "Safely Remove Drive":

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1067876

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1073597

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=598690#c5

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/706436

Also just to clarify, as mentioned in [What is the difference between "Unmount", "Eject", "Safely Remove Drive" and the eject icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5845/what-is-the-difference-between-unmount-eject-safely-remove-drive-and-the) or in [What is the difference between Eject and Safely Remove Device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86019/what-is-the-difference-between-eject-and-safely-remove-device?rq=1) Eject will also do the powering down but this does not work correctly on all devices. If the device has multiple partitions for example it might have problems when doing Eject.

Comment: Thanks, the first link appears to be it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1067876

Answer (score 1):

I've got Eject option in the right-click menu if I insert a USB drive. Clicking on the triangular icon next to the drive name in the right column does the same

[image]